# Change Form Action and Text Input Name based on Radio Input Checked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can I get some help with the following code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#searchform').submit(function() {

        var action = '';

        if($('.action_url').val() == 'l_catalog') {
            action = 'http://catalog.site.com/uhtbin/cgisirsi.exe/x/0/0/57/5';
            $("#s").attr('name','searchdata1');
        } else if ($('.action_url').val() == 'l_wordpress'){
            action = '<?php get_bloginfo('url') ?>';
            $("#s").attr('name','s');
        }

        $(this).attr('action', action);
        return true; // submit
    });

    $('.action_url').change();

});
```

I'm trying to use this function to set the action of a form to either a library catalog search page or the wordpress search page. Currently the radio buttons will select/deselect and will search the catalog only and not the wordpress. I had originally found this code online for a select form but now have to use radio buttons. (Having some difficulties). The PHP for this is:

```
$search_form .= '<form id="searchform" name="searchform" method="get" action="' . get_bloginfo('url') .'/">';
$search_form .= "\n" . "\t" . "\t";
$search_form .= '<div>';
$search_form .= "\n" . "\t" . "\t". "\t";
$search_form .= '<input type="radio" name="search_where" id="catalog" class="action_url" value="l_catalog" /> <label for="catalog">Library Catalog</label> <input type="radio" name="search_where" id="wordpress" class="action_url" value="l_wordpress" /> <label for="wordpress">Library Website</label>'; // <option value=\"l_catalog\">Library Catalog</option> \n \t \t \t \t <option value=\"l_wordpress\">Library Website</option>";
$search_form .= "\n" . "\t" . "\t". "\t";
if (is_search()) {
        $search_form .= '<input id="s" name="searchdata1" type="text" value="' . esc_html(stripslashes($_GET['s'])) .'" size="' . $search_form_length . '" tabindex="1" />';
} else {
        $value = __('To search, type and hit enter', 'thematic');
        $value = apply_filters('search_field_value',$value);
        $search_form .= '<input id="s" name="searchdata1" type="text" value="' . $value . '" onfocus="if (this.value == \'' . $value . '\') {this.value = \'\';}" onblur="if (this.value == \'\') {this.value = \'' . $value . '\';}" size="'. $search_form_length .'" tabindex="1" />';
}
$search_form .= "\n" . "\t" . "\t". "\t";

$search_form .= '<input name="srchfield1" type="hidden" value="GENERAL^SUBJECT^GENERAL^^words or phrase">';
$search_form .= '<input name="sort_by" type="hidden" value="-PBYR">';
$search_form .= '<input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="WSC">';
$search_form .= '<input name="password" type="hidden" value="">';

$search_form .= "\n" . "\t" . "\t". "\t";

$search_submit = '<input id="searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="' . __('Search', 'thematic') . '" tabindex="2" />';

$search_form .= apply_filters('thematic_search_submit', $search_submit);

$search_form .= "\n" . "\t" . "\t";
$search_form .= '</div>';

$search_form .= "\n" . "\t";
$search_form .= '</form>';
```

I'm sure this is messy, since I don't know PHP or Javascript very well and I'm trying to play in the Big League.

Comment: Is the js code generated in PHP? How are you including it on the html code?

Comment: You would be better served by using a query parameter to your search for what type of search you're doing. Changing the form action url after load is a security problem. If you can't get around that, you'll need to use iframes and that sucks more.

Comment: The JS is generated in a php page and it is being includeded like so:
include('includes/search.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in your JS:

```
action = '<?php get_bloginfo('url') ?>';
```

isn't going to work. `<?php ?>` tags a executed server side. JS code is executed in the browser.

You will need to specify the form's action url explicity: Similar to:

```
action = 'http://catalog.site.com/uhtbin/cgisirsi.exe/x/0/0/57/5';
```

I suggest that you create a hidden field:

```
$search_form .= '<input id="blog_url" type="hidden" value="' . get_bloginfo('url'). '">';
```

Your JS can then reference this browser side:

```
action = $('#blog_url').val();
```

Good luck!

Comment: OK, if the JS is generated server side. And changing form action url browser side is a secuity issue. Then maybe create 2 forms, one for each url. Wrap each form in a DIV and toggle the visibilty between each form depending on what radio button is selected. make sense?